# Tiktok Login Socialite

Tags: laravel, tiktok, redirect-uri

I am trying to implement the tiktok login kit on my laravel project. The project is on a dev environment and the information is set up correct on my code, but the app always sends me redirect_uri error.

```
[service][1]

[Login Kit][2]

[Platform info][3]
```

Answer (score 0):

well unfortunately im not a superhuman, i cant magically see your code or magically know what the error is since you put nothing in the post

But if you want to use Tiktok with Socialite, the recommended adapter is here:
https://socialiteproviders.com/TikTok

Comment: I actually followed that provider. I used that same provider.